# How to render grid in viewport (Ext.js)

Tags: extjs, grid, render, viewport

What's the right way to render panel(grid) in viewport?
Why the viewport is wrongly rendered while the initial example working well though: http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=simplevp

## My code (http://k-m.ru/extjs/viewport/)

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 

Ext.QuickTips.init();

var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
     id:'simplevp'
     //    ,renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    // renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    ,layout:'border'
    ,border:false
    ,items:[{
         region:'north'
        ,height:100
        ,border:false
        ,bodyStyle:'background-color:#f8f8f8;'
        ,title:'North'
        ,collapsible:true
        ,contentEl:'adsense-north'
    },{
         region:'west'
        ,width:200
        ,border:false
        ,autoScroll:true
        ,title:'West'
        ,bodyStyle:'padding:5px;font-size:11px;background-color:#f4f4f4;'
        ,html:' <h2>Hello from the West</h2>' 
        ,collapsible:true
        ,split:true
        ,collapseMode:'mini'

    },{
         region:'south'
        ,height:100
        ,html:'South'
        ,border:false
        ,title:'South'
        ,collapsible:true
    },{
         region:'east'
        ,width:200
        ,html:'East'
        ,border:false
        ,bodyStyle:'background-color:#f4f4f4;'
        ,title:'East'
        ,collapsible:true
    },{
         region:'center'
        ,html:'Center'
        ,border:false
        ,bodyStyle:'background-color:#f0f0f0;'
        ,title:'Center'
    /*  ,  items: [ 
                  {   xtype: 'Ext.grid.Panel', 
                      title: 'Заголовок панели 1', 
                      html:'Текст 1 текст 1 текст 1' 
                  }, 
                  {   xtype: 'panel', 
                      title: 'Заголовок панели 2', 
                      html:'Текст 1 текст  1 текст 1' 
                }]*/        
       }],


     }); // end of viewport
}); // eo function onReady
```

Comment: Would suggest updating to a newer version. 2.3.0 is very old and won't have support for modern browsers. The functionality is also a lot less.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli, it's ok, i'm going to do that with grid, yet, why it doesn't render viewport even without grid?

Comment: Yet, this link http://k-m.ru/extjs/app/extjs/ext-all-debug.js refers to v.4.2.0, the ext-base.js file is of v.2.3 though. Should i also change ext-base.js? If i'm not mistaken this file (http://k-m.ru/extjs/app/extjs/adapter/ext-base.js) refers to adapter for db, doesn't it?

Comment: No, has nothing to do with databases at all. I suggest you read the getting started guide.

Comment: The grids are misconfigured, the layout for the grid container isn't there. The `contentEl` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli, thank you. The **contentEl** has really misaligned everything. I think you are worth for me to check up your answer. Just compose it and i'll do it.